# Dynamic LINQ OrderBy for a Navigation Property using Expression in C#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I'm having two tables Namely Student and Mark

Table: `DbSet<StudentInfo>`

```
ID    Name
_____________________
1     Ram
2     Kumar
3     John
```

Table: `DbSet<ScoreInfo>`

```
Id    StudentId    Subject    Score
_____________________________________
1     1            GK         90
2     1            SCI        97
3     2            GK         81
4     2            SCI        99
```

The LINQ to SQL returns the following List

```
StudentId    Name    Subject    Score  
_____________________________________
1            Ram    GK         90
1            Ram    SCI        97
2            Kumar  GK         81
2            Kumar  SCI        99
3            John   null       null
```

The C# Code is

```
using(var db = new StudentEntity()) {
    var query = db.Student.Where(m => true);

    Expression<Func<StudentInfo,object>> sortExpression = null;

    if(sortColumn == "Name") {
        sortExpression = i => i.Name
    } else if(sortColumn == "Subject") {
        // ? How to achieve this
    }

    query = isAcending
                ? query.OrderBy(sortExpression)
                : query.OrderByDescending(sortExpression);

    query.Select(m => (...)).Dump();
}
```

The variable `sortColumn` is a `String`, which specifies the column need to sort and the variable `isAcending` is a `bool`, which specifies the sort direction.

I need to sort the Subject column. Kindly assist me how to write the `Expression<Func<StudentInfo,object>>` and the query should be `IQueryable` ?

Comment: you dont need to use Expressions directly when sorting. just use **query.OrderBy(x => x.Subject);**

Comment: minor pedantic point: Ascending has an `s` in it.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the way you'd write the lambda:

```
Expression<Func<StudentInfo,object>> sortExpression = si=>si.Name;
```

(Note that you can't use a `var` there because the compiler needs to know that you want it as an `Expression<T>`)

But your real problem is that you are trying to use a `StudentInfo` object, which you haven't created yet.  First you create one, then sort by it;

```
 db.Mark.Select(m=> new StudentInfo {
                    StudentID = m.StudentId, 
                    Name = m.Student.Name,
                    Subject = m.Subject,
                    Score = m.Score});

Expression<Func<StudentInfo, object>> sortExpression = null;

if (sortColumn == "Name")
{
    sortExpression = i => i.Name;

}
else if (sortColumn == "Subject")
{
    sortExpression = i => i.Subject;
}

    query = isAcending
                ? query.OrderBy(sortExpression)
                : query.OrderByDescending(sortExpression);

    return query;
```

Comment: FYI, the model `StudentInfo` is a Entity Framework Model Class, which is associate with the first table. The Navigation Property works like 'Left Outer Join' (i.e., Score table). I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass string to OrderBy method,
something like

`"colName ASC, anotherCol Desc, etc..."`

you can do something like this,

`string orderstring = sortColumnName +" "+ (isAcending ?? "ASC" : "DESC");
query  = query.OrderBy(orderstring);`